# Auto Build VSTS when code is pushed

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines

I have my repository on VSTS(visual studio team services). I have created steps where I can manually build from VSTS but I want to automate it:
**Whenever I PUSH any code in VSTS it should auto build my code.** What steps should I follow?

I have tried with the webhook trigger but it didn't work.
Tried below [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts) also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Continuous Integration](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/continuous-integration/). It's what you're looking for.

> Continuous Integration
>   Build every change to matching branches

You can setup your Build Definition to build each branch on a commit, or for instance only your master or develop branch.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to enable the Continuous Integration in your build definition:

Edit your build definition -> Triggers Tab -> Enable continuous integration -> specify Branch Filter or Path Filter for which branch/file to trigger the CI build -> save.

[image]